# php mysql_connect - Lost connection to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, connection

**this post has been edited to reflect the findings thus far between myself and iamkrillin, as we have been the only two posters**

I have the following VB.NET code connecting correctly, running from my PC

```
    Dim strConnection As String = "Server=dev.xxxxx.vmc;Database=report1;integrated security=SSPI;" & _ 
                                  "persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

    Dim ObjDa As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(pStrQuery, strConnection)

    Try
        Dim dsReturn As DataSet = New DataSet
        ObjDa.Fill(dsReturn)
        ObjDa.Dispose()
        Return dsReturn
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
```

---

---

I have the following PHP code running from our iSeries

```
$conn = array( 'host' => 'dev.xxxxx.vmc',
    'username' => 'vmc\adam',
    'password' => 'xxxxxx)',
    'dbname' => 'report1',
    'pdoType' => 'dblib' );

try {
    $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql($conn);
    $db->getConnection();
} catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {

}
```

The getConnection function, is throwing an error:

> SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)

And when I look up this error **[HERE](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48539&edit=1)**, it appears to be a bug PRE 5.2.10, and we are running 5.2.17.  But, some of the other comments say it is still a bug in 5.3.

---

**edit*

---

It seems that if using a domain account, windows auth must be enabled.  However, it is not through our PHP.  So I need to set up a database specific user for our PHP connection.

Comment: Why are you using the deprecated `mysql_` api?

Comment: When i use PDO with mysql, i get an error 'Can't connect to MySQL server on' probably because it's not an MySql database, it is a full SQL Server database.

Comment: When I posted that comment your code was using mysql... Anyway, you can use PDO for MSSQL, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VB snippet, you are connecting to SQL Server, and in your PHP snippet you are connecting to MySQL. If you need to use SQL Server from PHP, look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).  If you are on a non windows platform you can try [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/).  [Here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6636) is an example of how to get started with it

Comment: I agree, the problem is that all valid code I find is for MySql, which is not what i want.  The system requirements for your link are all windows, but we are running PHP on our iSeries [IBM] server.

Comment: in that case you might try looking at FreeTDS.

Comment: I actually just found a post suggesting to use mssql as the driver in the connection for PDO:    PDO('mssql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'    However, I get an error 'could not find driver'.  When I look in our zend server, mssql is enabled and running.  I'd rather go this route than putting in yet another extension.

Comment: try setting up your connection like so  $dbAdapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql(array(
 'host'     => '192.xxx.xxx.xxx', // parklife
 'username' => 'xxx',
 'password' => 'xxx',
 'dbname'   => 'xxx',
'pdoType'  =>  'dblib' )
 );

Comment: Here is another example of how to set it up (zend + pdo) http://php4u.co.uk/2010/06/use-php-and-pdo-to-connect-to-ms-sql-server-zend-framework/

Comment: ahh, this is aggravating. I feel like it's so close. I'll update my post with the issue now.  I do appreciate all your help!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17146/discussion-between-iamkrillin-and-adam)